# Beginner's guide to writing grammar

Tags: java, antlr, parser-generator

The application I am working inputs lot of data from file import and updates the database column accordingly. I need to come up with a custom Rule engine that would process all the input values based on validation and perform transformation of data accordingly. E.x.

One of the fields in our application is Product Name. So one of the rules we need to implement is to convert Product name from lower case to upper case, if the input value from the file is in lower case. Similarly, there are many text/mathematical transformations that need to be done. For these reasons, we need to come up with custom rule engine where we define the rules for each attribute, parse them and then apply the rules.

I do know that [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) is one of the parser generators around for `Java`. I am seeking advice on following queries:
1> General information on working of a parser generator and best practices for implementing grammar.

2> Since I need to design this rule engine completely, can anyone point me to a sample rule engine out there that I can refer to? right from UI to database design. I am using GWT for UI, Java for core logic and oracle for database

3> Are there any other parser generators around for Java

4> Though I do want to follow the path of defining my own grammar and using parser generator to build this rule engine, is there any other approach I should consider?

Comment: It seems like a grammar is a bit overkill for this, unless the file is quite structurally complex a grammar will probably only make your life harder. Simple string testing, switch statements and such ought to be enough.

Comment: Well, the rules we have currently are only to start with. As I said, there would be string/mathematical transformations now and so I was not sure if "Simple string testing, switch statements" would scale well when we have more complex ones coming in. I am not sure if Regex would be best here as well

Comment: The way you have described your problem, it isn't clear what the limits are on selecting columns to combine, choosing output columns, or doing arbitrary computations over this data.  If you cannot define a trustworthy set of *limits* on what you are allowed to do, you will need the full power of a Turing capable language (Java seems fine); to get to all the columns and records, you will likely need at least the power of SQL just for data access and update.  Do you have clear limits on what you are willing to compute? and why do you think yet another language will be helpful for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to consider just using JbossRules (formerly Drools) which is a Java based rules engine.  Alternatively, a scripting engine may be another way to implement your rules (e.g. Apache Rhino (Javascript in Java)).

Writing your own in this situation seems like overkill, but it may allow you to provide better security guarantees if end users are going to be creating the rules / scripts.

EDIT to address questions in comments:

I suggest using an existing rules engine (ala JbossRules/Drools) instead of writing your own parser and grammar (for the rule component).  Take a look here for instance: [Drools](http://www.jboss.org/drools/drools-expert.html).

For specialized logic that rules may need to use (db access or computation libraries) you should write a single Java API used by your rules (so that rules are not deeply accessing your other code since that can lead to bugs if/when you refactor).  This advice applies regardless of which rules engine you use (your own or an existing one).

I assume that you already have the data format of your data input files solved and that you are only looking for a solution to the rule format and rule parsing.

Comment: thanks for your input. The rule engine will be used by the "functional" folks here and won't be available for public use in our application. But I thought of using a parser generator because the re can be any level of nesting for the transformation rules. Do you think parser generator is the right way to take?

Comment: Did you suggest not using the rule engine with our custom grammar or not using rules at all?

Comment: @darkie15 Updated answer to address your questions.

Answer (score 1):

There is JavaCC, which is a Parser generator and there is groovy for evaluating rules. If you are going to use a script engine or not depends on the grammar. If the rules can't be expressed in javascript, java, python, etc, and you want to write them in a new language, well then you have to use a parser generator. But you can always do anything you want inside methods that you create and then call them from the rules. The rules will be evaluated by the script engine.